# Digital Sensors for Single Board Computers

Tags: embedded-systems

I'm looking for some digital sensors, (temperature, pressure, lux, humidity), that I can run for a long distance, (80m).

The onewire temperature DS18B20 sensor looks good, (https://www.adafruit.com/product/381), but I couldn't find much else.

Does anyone know of onewire equivalents for the above sensor types and preferably cheaper temperature sensors as I need to purchase 20!

Comment: Do you have a budget? And are those the only four measurements you want the sensor to take?

Comment: @Adam they are the only measurement but will not be taken from the same source, e.g lux corridor lighting, temp of office room, etc.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding anything inexpensive off the shelf that will handle that distance without an intermediate board to perform logical and electrical translation to a scheme suitable for distance.  It might be as practical to look for a low cost RS485 MCU board that could host and proxy for various I2C peripherals.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could you recommend any such boards?

Comment: I'm not sure what is available off the shelf (and that would be an off-topic sourcing question anyway), but if you put a little ARM Cortex M0 or ATmega on a simple board with an RS485 transceiver that should give you a generic starting point, and you can save costs by making a half dozen identical boards that can handle different sensors.  If you were clever, you might make the board have breadboard compatible headers, but also give it footprints to host a few different surface mount sensors of interest.